# no module name datetime after ubuntu 13.04 upgrade

Tags: django, ubuntu, python-2.7, virtualenv

Just did an upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 and getting this when running django site in virtualenv

```
(virtualenv)sysadmin@ubuntu:~/webapps/devsite/djangosite$ ./manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
  File "/home/sysadmin/webapps/devsite/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError, handle_default_options
  File "/home/sysadmin/webapps/devsite/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
  File "/home/sysadmin/webapps/devsite/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 4, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

Comment: Doesn't 13.04 now come with Python 3? Not sure if that has any effect on the older virtualenv.

Comment: my default python is 2.7.4 
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2

Comment: Can you import datetime after activating your virtualenv in console?

Comment: no, I can't.
sysadmin@ubuntu:~/webapps/defsite$ . virtualenv/bin/activate
(virtualenv)sysadmin@ubuntu:~/webapps/defsite$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named datetime
>>>

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just do

```
virtualenv /home/sysadmin/webapps/devsite/virtualenv/
```

this will reinstall Python in the VirtualEnv and it will work after that (and you won't need to reinstall the libraries).

---

Update: when I was dealing with the same problem after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10, virtualenv didn't want to overwrite the existing symlink to Python, so I had to remove it first (in this example that would be `rm /home/sysadmin/webapps/devsite/virtualenv/python`)

Comment: Debian testing, the same issue.
Works OK after a virtualenv was reinstalled.

Comment: I had to delete `bin/python` links first then run `mkvirtualenv venv` since I'm using virtualenvwrapper